# Why does "col" variable return a wrong value

Tags: java

In a recent job interview, I had to solve a programmatic question. The question was to convert a given excel alphabet column name to a column number. My solution worked for the most part until they (interviewer) gave me "AUHS" as a column name. The solution broke. The expected answer "31999" but I got "18999". I want to learn where I went wrong and what I could do to improve the solution.

PS: I am **new** to Java

My solution,

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String argChar = "AUHS";

        char a = 'A';
        int asciiA = (int) a;

        int col = 0;
        col += Math.pow(26, 0) + (int)argChar.charAt(argChar.length()-1) - asciiA;

        for(int i=1; i<argChar.length(); i++) {
            col += (int)(Math.pow(26, i) + ((int)argChar.charAt(argChar.length()-(i+1)) - asciiA) * 26);
        }

        System.out.println(col);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the expected answer 31999? Describe your logic verbally.

Comment: What do you mean by `excel alphabet column name to a column number`? Is it related to the spreadsheet columns in Excel, which are composed of two letters like [described here](https://www.vishalon.net/blog/excel-column-letter-to-number-quick-reference#columnaaaz) ?

Comment: @khelwood, on Excel spreadsheet, if you scroll right, the column number represented by "AUSH" column header name would be "31999". A similar example, 27 is column header "AA", 28 is column header "AB", and so on. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @hc_dev, yes, it is related to the Excel spreadsheet header. So, I needed to write a program in Java to convert alphabetic column names to their respective column number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The formula for spreadsheets's alphabetical column labels

The sequence of A-Z encoded (base-26) column-labels is:

```
A .. 1 (= 26^0*1)
B .. 2 (= 26^0*2)
H .. 2 (= 26^0*8)
S .. 2 (= 26^0*19)
U .. 2 (= 26^0*21)
Z .. 26 (= 26^0*26)

AA .. 27 (= 26^1*1 +1)
AZ .. 52 (= 26^1*1 +26)  
BA .. 53 (= 26^1*2 +1)
ZZ .. 702 (= 26^1*26 +26)

AAA .. 703 (= 26^2*1 + 26^1*1 + 26^0*1)
UHS .. 14423 (= 26^2*21 + 26^1*8 + 26^0*19)
AUHS .. 31999 (= 26^3*1 + 26^2*21 + 26^1*8 + 26^0*19)
```

So we can deduct the formula (in pseudo-mathematical-notation) as:

```
  sum-of ( 26^index * letterAsNumber ) over each letter
  where index is the position of the letter from the end starting with 0
  where letterAsNumber is the letter mapped to a number {1..26}
  where letter must be in range {A..Z}
```

See also [Positional notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation).

### The parts of this formula in Java

Given following inputs:

- column-label `String columnLabel`
- base `int radix = 26`
- ASCII-code offset `int asciiOffset = 65 - 1` (`A` has the decimal ASCII code `65`)

We need to calculate the following working variables:

- backwards-index `int backwardsIndex`, which is initially `0` and is incremented by 1 when iterating through each character; starting at the end of the column-label (hence: *backwards*!)
- the *running* column-number `long columnNumber`, where a column-letters numerical-character-representation will be added during each iteration

#### The formula in Java

```
    final int asciiOffset = (int) 'A' - 1; // 64 = 65 - 1, so that (int) 'B' - asciiOffset == 2
    long columnNumber = 0;

    for (int backwardsIndex=0; backwardsIndex < columnLabel.length(); backwardsIndex++) {
        char letter = columnLabel.charAt(columnLabel.length() - backwardsIndex -1);
        int letterAsNumber = (int) letter - asciiOffset;
        columnNumber += Math.pow(26, backwardsIndex) * letterAsNumber;
    }

    return columnNumber;
}
```

See working [demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/2Pn8Jo).

#### Issues in your code

What I did to show them:

- split some statements of yours into meaningful and testable parts
- commented the issues (actual values and expected)
- added an `assert` below some lines (to verify expected values)
- added a fixing statement below (with some explanation)

```java
String argChar = "AUHS";

// int asciiA = (int) 'A'; // actual: 65; expected: 64
int asciiA = (int) 'A' - 1; // should be an offset to have: (int) `A` - offset == 1
assert asciiA == 64;

int col = 0;
char letter = argChar.charAt(argChar.length()-1); // actual == expected: 'S'
int letterAsNumber = (int) letter - asciiA; // actual: 83 - 65: expected: 83 - 64;
assert letterAsNumber == 19;
// col += Math.pow(26, 0) + letterAsNumber; // actual: 20 = 1 + 19; expected: 19 = 1 * 19
col = (int) Math.pow(26, 0) * letterAsNumber; // multiply instead add
assert col == 19;

for(int i=1; i<argChar.length(); i++) {
    letter = argChar.charAt(argChar.length() - (i + 1));
    // letterAsNumber = ((int) letter - asciiA) * 26;
    letterAsNumber = ((int) letter - asciiA); // should not add 26 at the end
    // col += Math.pow(26, i) + letterAsNumber;
    col += Math.pow(26, i) * letterAsNumber; // multiply instead add
}
assert col == 31999;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I can’t do an upvote because my reputation is below 15. So, literally “thumb up” from me for now.

Comment: @dobby, you may not be able to upvote but you should be able to accept this answer because it's worth it.  Cheers!

Comment: @hc_dev just wanted to say, thanks for the help on the code and especially for pointing me to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation. The Wikipedia link helped a bunch. I gave you an upvote. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

As counting starts from 1, and columns are counted from `A`, a correction `argChar.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1` is needed to properly convert chars to digits:

```java
String argChar = "AUHS";
int pow = 1;
int n = 0;
for (int i = argChar.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    n += (argChar.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1) * pow;
    pow *= 26;
}
System.out.println("n = " + n);
```

Output:

```
n = 31999
```

Comment: __Looping backwards__ (`i--`) is a very natural and readable improvement.
The explanation of char-to-digit conversion is not that obvious, as some peers may not have started with Java 1.0 as we did  Thus they might be _digital-natives_, but not _ASCII-natives_.

Comment: @hc_dev, 1) I upvoted your answer - you took your time and provided really good explanation 2) My answer was _submitted_ later than yours due to some technical issues on my side

Comment: 1) Upvoted yours too - you solved it fairly concisely and briefly, pointing out the main cause.
2) Just wanted to encourage you to write your explanation of: _relative_ ASCII-code = relative column-number thing. Since I think this is the _hardest_ part here and deserves more perspectives / explanation.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexRudenko. I gave an upvote for your help.